# Search for character in string, within an loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have a string containing 3 different types of characters with a special meaning. I have an loop that iterates 160times, and for each iteration of the loop, I want to check the current character in the string. Thus, if it is the first iteration of the loop, I want to check the first position in the string and check what kind of character it is. If it is the second iteration, I want to check the second position in the string etcetc.

How can I do this in AngularJS?

I'm returning the string from my php backend.

Here is the solution in PHP, but I want it to work with AngularJS:

```
<?php
$string = "........####........
.....##..##.........
......#.......&&&&&&
......&&&&&&........
.&..&&&....%..##.&&&
&&......##......&&&.
....................
.#..................";

$k = 1;
for($j = 1; $j <= 8; $j++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++)
    {   
        if($string[$k] == "#")
        {
            echo "<td id='$k'>#</td>";
        }
        elseif($string[$k] == "&")
        {
            echo "<td class='click' val='water' id='$k'>&</td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td class='click' id='$k'><a href='#'></a></td>";
        }
        $k++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Here is my controller in AngularJS:

```
gameApp.controller("gameCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location) {
    $scope.trr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    $scope.tdd = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    $scope.getMonsters = "1";
    var map;

    $http.post("lib/action.php", {monsters: $scope.getMonsters}).success(function(data) {
        map = data;
        console.log(map);
    });

    if(link.user) {
        /*$scope.message = "fisk";
        console.log(link.user);*/
    } else {
        /*$scope.message = "Ledsen fisk";
        console.log("Är inte satt");*/
    }
});
```

Here is my PHP-backend:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("classes.php");
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if(isset($data))
    {
        $objData = json_decode($data);
        $login = new User();
        echo $login->doLogin($objData->username, $objData->password);

        if(isset($objData->monsters)) 
        {
            $string = "........####.............##..##...............#.......&&&&&&......&&&&&&.........&..&&&....%..##.&&&&&......##......&&&......................#..................";
            echo $string;
        }
    }
```

Here is my HTML with my looop:

```
<div ng-controller="gameCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in trr">
        <td ng-repeat="r in tdd"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Anyone who can help me?

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you simply create a function in Javascript that does exactly the same :

```
function makeTableFrom(str) {

  var k = 1,
    result = "";

  for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    result += '<tr>';

    for (var j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {

      if (str[k] === '#') {
        result += '<td id="' + k + '">#</td>';
      }
      else if (str[k] === '&') {
        result += '<td class="click" val="water" id="' + k + '">&</td>';
      }
      else {
        result += '<td class="click" id="' + k + '"><a href="#"></a></td>';
      }

      k++;
    }

    result += '</tr>';
  }

  return result;
}
```

and call it from the success function of your post request :

```
$http.post("lib/action.php", {monsters: $scope.getMonsters}).success(function(data) {
  map = data;
  console.log(map);
  // say result is declared outside
  result = makeTableFrom(data);
  // now use it as intended
});
```

However, let me be clear about the fact that, in your php function or in this one, your calls to `$string[$k]` or `str[k]` should be with `k-1` because of the offset in string indexing...

Here is a link to a JSFiddle that illustrates the difference : http://jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/hmutk1y5/

**UPDATE:**

To use the resulting string as inner HTML for your table, you should use `ng-bind-html` in combination with the ngSanitize module, like so :

```
<div ng-app="gameApp">
  <div ng-controller="gameCtrl">
    <table ng-bind-html="gameTable">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then **don't forget to add angular-sanitize.js to your resources** and to add it to your app :

```
angular.module('gameApp', ['ngSanitize'])
```

And edit your `$http.post().success()` function :

```
$http.post("lib/action.php", {monsters: $scope.getMonsters}).success(function(data) {
  map = data;
  console.log(map);

  $scope.gameTable = makeTableFrom(data); // Where you update the table depending on your ajax call
});
```

Link to the updated JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/hmutk1y5/1/

Comment: Thank you very much. It was easier than I thought. But how do I "parse" the result to my HTML page? It seems very difficult to parse html to the view using angularjs. Is there an another way?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse" in HTML? If you mean insert it in a `table` tag, there is an example in the JSFiddle using jQuery.

Comment: The result variable in your example contains the table data with the td's and tr's. How do I print out the value in the result variable inside the <table></table> in my view-file?